# Local echo is not shown correctly in a shell, if cursor is shifted to the left

Tags: terminal, freebsd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am connected to a FreeBSD12.1 SSH server with WSL(Win10 Linux).

When I shift the cursor to the left while already created a command, every char I enter overwrites the local echo. But internally the command is shifted correct.

Example:

```
$> cat /tmp/log
Then place the cursor to the beginning and add 'sudo', I will see
$> sudo/tmp/log
But as I hit return, the correct command with be processed: 'sudo cat /tmp/log'
```

`echo $0` reads `/bin/csh`

Distribution is OpnSense 21.7

So its more a display problem. What am I missing here?
Definitely the problem is already answered somewhere, but I am missing the correct search pattern to find the answer.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention your terminal, but it *sounds* like you are experiencing [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1947) in Windows Terminal (also manifested as described in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6652)) due to the lack of Insertion-Replacement Mode even though it's telling BSD that it supports the xterm codes.

If that's the case, there's a potential workaround mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1947#issuecomment-660628728), which is to create a `~/.termcap` on the server with (and only with):

```
xterm-256color:mi@:IC=\E[%d@:ei@:ic=\E[@:im@:tc=xterm-new:
```

Comment: I have no idea what the above statement does. But this totally does the trick, Thank you very much. Terminal is "Windows Terminal" if this is the one when 'wsl' is called..

Comment: @crazyduck That's probably the "old" Windows Console (precursor to the new Windows Terminal) that's being called when you just run `wsl` by itself.  But they are both from Microsoft, so I'm guessing they never got around to implementing it in the older one either.  Still, would recommend upgrading to Windows Terminal -- Go to the Microsoft Store and search for it.  It will automatically detect your WSL installation (and most other shells) and create menu entries for them.  It's also (a) open-source, (b) in active development, and (c) has tons of upgrades, including tabs.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I would up vote your comment, but have to less reputation on "Unix&Linux"

Comment: @crazyduck No worries - Your upvote will count eventually when you do get the rep.  I believe it's 50, but could be less.  Thanks, and glad I could help!